# Problems with Vhost on Ubuntu 12.04 + Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

maybe somone can point me in the right direction with this. A Domain (kat.mydomain.de) pointed to a Ubuntu Server. We set up a new server and changed the Ip adress of the url to the new Server Ip. This seems to work (if I check this with trace).

On the new Ubuntu 12.04 runs a Apache/2.2.22. Apache should now redirect the url to the Folder   /var/www/kat as the old server did. (The root Folder is /var/www)

Under /etc/apache2/sites-available reside 
default and
default-ssl

default looks like this (only the important looking part)

```
   <Directory />   
       Options None
       AllowOverride All
       Deny from all
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

       <Directory /var/www/kat>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
       </Directory>

    <VirtualHost *>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *>
        ServerName kat.mydomain.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/kat
    </VirtualHost>
```

Under /etc/apache2/sites-enable reside
000-default and 
000-default_bak

which I can post when needed. But will not by now because of there length.

$ apache2ctl -S

gives me:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*      ds80-234-188-100.dedicated.hosteurope.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:65)
*:*      kat.mydomain.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:89)
*:80     is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ds80-234-188-100.dedicated.hosteurope.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default_bak:1)
         port 80 namevhost ds80-234-188-100.dedicated.hosteurope.de (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default_bak:1)
Syntax OK
```

Of course I tried to setup a new conf file in sites-available for the vhost and enabled it with en2site. Which didn´t work either. All calls to kat.mydomain.de end in the root dir /var/www.

Thankful for every help,

tony

Comment: oh now seems NameVirtualHost * was missing!

Comment: you mean you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `NameVirtualHost *` to get this working